# How to remove the "today" vertical line from my Gantt chart

Tags: r, gantt-chart, diagrammer

I've created a simple Gantt chart in R (my first) using the DiagrammeR package, but I can't work out how to remove the red vertical line (representing today) from the chart. Also, for some reason, March displays as w.17 on the x-axis rather than 03-17? Any ideas very welcome.

Code is as follows

```
library(Diagrammer)

m1 <- mermaid("
        gantt
              dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
              title Research Proposal Timeline

              section Tidy Raw Data
              Tidy available data            :active,        first_1,   2017-03-01, 14d
              New data                      :active,        first_2,   2017-06-01, 7d

              section Alignment and Assemply
              Align & Assign RNASeq Dataset          :crit, active,  align_1,    2017-03-15, 14d
              Align & Assign Epic Array Dataset      :crit, active,  align_2,    2017-03-20, 14d
              Assemble Methylome                     :crit, active,  align_3,    align_2, 14d
              Assemble Genotype & Phenotype Tables   :crit, active,  align_4,    after align_3, 5d

              section Data Analysis
              Development of Pipeline       :active,        pipe_1,     2017-04-01, 156d
              Debugging Script              :active         pipe_2,     2017-04-11, 146d
              Student Development           :active         pipe_3,     2017-03-01, 200d

              section Results
              Define Biomarkers of interest :active,        results_1,   2017-06-01, 5d
              Establish Predictive Model    :active,        results_2,   2017-06-01, 14d
              Test Predictive Model         :active,        results_3,   2017-06-08, 10d

              section Assessments
              Written Research Proposal     :active,        extras_1,   2017-02-20, 16d               
              Research Proposal Seminar     :active,        extras_2,   2017-03-06, 15d
              Non-Expert Seminar            :active,        extras_3,   2017-04-01, 10d
              Draft Literature Review       :active,        extras_4,   2017-03-21, 77d
              Literature Review             :active,        extras_5,   2017-05-22, 14d
              Literature Assessment Task    :active,        extras_6,   2017-07-04, 24h
              Research Progress Seminar     :active,        extras_7,   2017-08-01, 20d
              Thesis                        :crit, active,  extras_8,   2017-08-04, 94d
              VIVA                          :crit, active,  extras_9,   2017-11-07, 24h
              ", height = 400, width = 1000)

m1
```

The code is modified from a previous reply from George Dontas.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off the marker for the current day with:
todayMarker off

Comment: This works great! To make it even more understandable, you should add `todayMarker off` to your YAML settings of your mermaid.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the line if you use the [style_widget function from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222202156/https://buildingwidgets.com/blog/2016/9/7/custom-styling-for-htmlwidgets). Then you can call

```
style_widget(m1, "display:none", "line.today")
```

[image]

The function is copied here for completeness

```
style_widget <- function(hw=NULL, style="", addl_selector="") {
  stopifnot(!is.null(hw), inherits(hw, "htmlwidget"))

  # use current id of htmlwidget if already specified
  elementId <- hw$elementId
  if(is.null(elementId)) {
    # borrow htmlwidgets unique id creator
    elementId <- sprintf(
      'htmlwidget-%s',
      htmlwidgets:::createWidgetId()
    )
    hw$elementId <- elementId
  }

  htmlwidgets::prependContent(
    hw,
    htmltools::tags$style(
      sprintf(
        "#%s %s {%s}",
        elementId,
        addl_selector,
        style
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant @MrFlick I have added your `style_widget` function and the line is gone - and thank you for the introduction to leaflet.

Comment: @MrFlick the link to your function is broken. Could you update it please?

Comment: @CorinaRoca I updated the link to use the internet archive.

Comment: Thank you! Is it the same that the one on this package, right? https://rdrr.io/github/BAAQMD/lltools/src/R/style_widget.R